# phalcon volt engine with getters and setters

Tags: phalcon, volt

I want try this framework, but i have a problem. 
i am create a application via phalcon-dev-tools

```
phalcon project phalcon
```

after this i create table `users` with 2 field = id, login

then

```
 phalcon scaffold --table-name=users --get-set --force --template-engine=volt
```

Model with protected attribute with public methods - its okey

in volt `{{ user.id }}` return null, because its try to ger property `id` not method `getId()`

why?

ps. phalcon 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You could call:
{{ user.getId() }} from Volt.

Are you expecting it to behave differently?